# Join table to get the latest rows from unique row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two table

The table structure goes something like this

Table A

```
╔══════╦════════╗
║ P_ID ║ P_NAME ║
╠══════╬════════╣
║    1 ║ name1  ║
║    2 ║ name2  ║
║    3 ║ name3  ║
║    4 ║ name5  ║
╚══════╩════════╝
```

Table B

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID  ║  P_ID  ║  C_ID  ║  C_PRICE  ║  TIME ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║  1  ║      1 ║      3 ║        11 ║ 11111 ║
║  2  ║      2 ║      4 ║        22 ║ 22222 ║
║  3  ║      3 ║      5 ║        33 ║ 33333 ║
║  4  ║      3 ║      6 ║        44 ║ 44444 ║
║  5  ║      3 ║      6 ║        55 ║ 55555 ║
║  6  ║      4 ║      7 ║        66 ║ 66666 ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

The requirement is 
1. Join two table 
2. Group By C_ID
3. The latest rows in Group By

I tried to modify the answer By Bill Karwin from [How do I join the most recent row in one table to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497535/how-do-i-join-the-most-recent-row-in-one-table-to-another-table/498179#498179)

```
SELECT e.*, s1.*  
FROM table_a e   
INNER JOIN
table_b s1
    ON (e.p_id = s1.p_id)   
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b s2
    ON (e.p_id = s2.p_id AND s1.id < s2.id) 
WHERE s2.p_id IS NULL;
```

but I could not achieve what I want. From his answer I will get

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ ID  ║  P_ID  ║  C_ID  ║  C_PRICE  ║  TIME ║  P_NAME ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║  1  ║      1 ║      3 ║        11 ║ 11111 ║ name1   ║
║  2  ║      2 ║      4 ║        22 ║ 22222 ║ name2   ║
║  5  ║      3 ║      6 ║        55 ║ 55555 ║ name3   ║
║  6  ║      4 ║      7 ║        66 ║ 66666 ║ name5   ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

But the output what I want is as below ( dublicate P_ID is ok but for each dublicate P_ID should not have dublicate C_ID )

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ ID  ║  P_ID  ║  C_ID  ║  C_PRICE  ║  TIME ║  P_NAME ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║  1  ║      1 ║      3 ║        11 ║ 11111 ║ name1   ║
║  2  ║      2 ║      4 ║        22 ║ 22222 ║ name2   ║
║  3  ║      3 ║      5 ║        33 ║ 33333 ║ name3   ║
║  5  ║      3 ║      6 ║        55 ║ 55555 ║ name3   ║
║  6  ║      4 ║      7 ║        66 ║ 66666 ║ name5   ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Here what is `LEFT OUTER JOIN scores s2
    ON (e.p_id = s2.p_id AND s1.id < s2.id)` ??

Comment: sorry, edited ( scores -> table_b )

Comment: done formatting your question `:D`

Comment: @KuyaJohn Thanks alot :)... how to do that?, or is it just simple table html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, s1.*
FROM table_a e INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_b ORDER BY time DESC) temp GROUP BY c_id) s1;
```

The innermost ORDER BY ensures the for the same c_id the desired row always comes first, the outter GROUP BY will group on c_id, and having not specified otherwise will return the first row found for each group.

Comment: I assumed by "the latest" you mean the field time, but now I see you used id. If id is good for you then use that instead of time (especially if it happens to be a primary key, as the name suggests).

Comment: ahhh finally... u forget the WHERE clause WHERE e.P_ID = s1.P_ID;  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38554/15

Answer (score 0):

You must

1. Join two table
2. Group By C_ID
3. Number row for each group desc ordered by chosen field (last imply order!)
4. Filter by row number  = 1.

[This](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#1098) can help you for numbering rows.