# Filtering out most recent row in a join query

Tags: mysql, join, groupwise-maximum

I have 2 tables with the following information. Unfortunately my basic knowledge of JOINS & MySQL isn't helping me achieve the result set I need... point 3 in particular is eluding me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

ORDERS

```
OrderID     OrderDate   Client      Country 

68349       1/1/2018    GSC Ltd     US
93909       1/1/2018    XYZ Ltd     UK
39900       3/31/2018   ABC Ltd     US
69382       4/4/2018    ABC Ltd     US
94500       6/21/2018   DEF Ltd     US
93911       1/1/2018    TUV Ltd     UK
```

REPORTS

```
RepID   State   RepDate     Building    OrderID

1   AK  1/1/2018    PE James    93909
2   CA  4/2/2018    PE Grid     93909
3   CA  3/31/2018   PMU Jaya    39900
4   WA  4/4/2018    PMU Taman   69382
5   CA  6/21/2018   PE Grid     94500
6   CA  3/31/2018   PMU Wate    39900
```

I need to select all based on :

1. Select orders where the Country is = US
2. Select reports that were a part of those US Orders (ie Order ID = Order ID from result above)
3. Most importantly: Filter the result of the reports so that it **only shows the single latest Report (based on most Recent RepDate) for each Building**

So the results would be:

```
OrderID     OrderDate   Client      Country     RepID   RepDate     Building 

68349       1/1/2018    GSC Ltd     US      -   -       -
39900       3/31/2018   ABC Ltd     US      3   3/31/2018   PMU Jaya
69382       4/4/2018    ABC Ltd     US      4   4/4/2018    PMU Taman
94500       6/21/2018   DEF Ltd     US      5   6/21/2018   PE Grid
```

The result below would be **excluded** since there is a more recent report for "PE Grid":

```
OrderID     OrderDate   Client      Country     RepID   RepDate     Building 

39900       3/31/2018   ABC Ltd     US      6   3/31/2018   PE Grid
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `OrderDate` and `RepDate` field(s) ?

Comment: They are DATE fields. The actual table is in YYYY-MM-DD format.. but I just made the date easier to read here. Hope that's okay.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Kristy. For future reference, it's wise to give your question a descriptive titile. It helps others with similar problems find your question and any answers. I've taken the liberty of editing this title.

Comment: This is a(n obvious & easlily found) faq. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I join the most recent row in one table to another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497535/how-do-i-join-the-most-recent-row-in-one-table-to-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest report for each building is the trick here. First, you need to find the date of the latest report, like this.

```
               SELECT MAX(RepDate) RepDate, Building
                 FROM reports
                GROUP BY RepDate
```

GROUP BY guarantees you'll have only one row here per building.

Then you need to treat that query as a virtual table and join to it. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ade437e/2/0)

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.Client, o.Country,
       r.RepId, r.RepDate, r.Building
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN reports r ON o.OrderID = r.OrderID
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(RepDate) RepDate, Building
                FROM reports
                GROUP BY RepDate
            ) m ON r.RepDate = m.RepDate AND r.Building = m.Building
```

Notice the use here of `LEFT JOIN`. That means orders with no matching report will still show up in the result set. If you don't want those orders, change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

If you want to filter that result set add `WHERE o.Country = 'US'` (or the filter of your choice) to the end of the query. Then you can use `ORDER BY` to sort the result set if that's what you need.

The trick is to build the query from the inside out.

By the way, this is called the [*greatest n per group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) pattern.